# C++/CLI application hanging after compiling on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2013, c++-cli, windows-10

I have a mixed managed and unmanaged C++ application that's working quite well. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 to compile it, and all is well. Recently I upgraded my computer to Windows 10, and now it's not working.

If I get the executable compiled on Windows 8, it runs properly on Windows 10. It only fails if I compile it on Windows 10.

The failure is peculiar as well. I run the EXE and nothing happens. When I run it from Visual Studio it doesn't even reach the first line of `main`. Breakpoints are all marked as 'disabled'. When I break the running process the debugger shows an empty stack trace.

UPDATE: Hunch about DLL loading turned into a fact:

I used [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and I see the process has two threads. The one starting at !CorExeMain is stuck at !LdrLoadDll, but I can't tell which DLL that is.

OK, found the DLL that causes the problem. I've created a C++/CLI console application, used that DLL and got the same behavior. The DLL is part of the application (and part of the VS solution). It's a native C++ DLL, compiled with the same compiler and settings. This DLL references *other* DLLs unfortunately.

Comment: Are you still using the VS2013 compiler on Windows10 (i.e. same platform toolset)?

Comment: Yep. I don't have Visual Studio 2015 installed.

Comment: Seems to me that it doesn't even load the CLR. Could you reproduce by creating a simple console app and running that one?  BTW: did you compile and run in debug mode?

Comment: A dummy console app works - C++/CLI. The problem exhibits itself both in Debug and Release mode.

Comment: Hm, then you may have to remove as much as needed from your app until it works again. Afterwards you gotta add parts until it fails in order to see what causes the failure. Alternatively, you could build up another similar app and fill it up with your code until it fails.

Comment: If it's a DLL for sure, build a dummy console app, include DLL #1 and use some functions of that DLL. Compile, run, check. Go on until DLL #n...

Comment: Found the DLL. It's one of the application's DLL. I'm rather stuck now, how can I proceed?

Comment: Is it your own DLL or did you get it from s.o. else? Is it a managed DLL or a native C++ DLL? Anyway: reference only this DLL in the test app to ensure it's this DLL only and not a combination of DLLs. If it's your own DLL: Did you compile the faulty DLL on W10+VS2013, too, or did you copy it from your previous system? I suggest you compile this DLL again on the new system.

Comment: Added info to the question. The DLL has been, of course, compiled again (a Rebuild All takes care of that)

Comment: made an answer from my comments and added the next step

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a generic problem called "LoaderLock".  The operating system makes very strong guarantees when it calls the DllMain() entrypoint of a DLL.  Strictly in loading order, they never run at the same time.  There is a lock in the OS loader that ensures these promises are kept.

And a lock always has the potential to cause deadlock.  It will happen when the DllMain() entrypoint does something unwise like loading the DLL itself with LoadLibrary().  Or call a function that requires the OS to have a DLL already loaded.  Can't work, its DllMain() entrypoint can't be called because the loader lock is held.  The program will freeze.  C++/CLI apps are prone to this problem, lots of stuff tends to happen in DllMain().  Indirectly, you can't see it in your code.

You can only see it with the debugger.  You must change its flavor, Project > Properties > Debugging > Debugger Type, change it from "Auto" to "Mixed".  You'll now also see the unmanaged code that is running including the OS loader functions, name starts with "Ldr".  Be sure to enable the Microsoft Symbol Server with Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols.  And be sure to use the Debug > Windows > Threads debugging window as well, the truly tricky loader deadlocks that don't repeat well or appear to be affected by the OS version are caused by another thread loading a DLL.

Diagnosing and fixing it can be difficult, be sure to reserve the time you need to dig in.  If you can't make heads or tails of the stack traces then post them in your question.

Comment: Thanks. The strange thing is that if the application is *compiled* on Windows 8 I can run it on Windows 10. If it is compiled on Windows 10 it freezes.

Comment: It is very, very, very important to stop reasoning from "it used to work".  Very high odds that your program always had this problem but just didn't trigger it by accident.  You can't wish it away, you must grab that bull by the horns.  Reserve the time, you'll be at it for a while.

Comment: I've inherited this application, and it does indeed loads multiple DLLs by itself. I'm still uncertain as to exactly what or where. Fortunately, most of these DLLs are native.

I'm still wondering why the system the *compiler* is on affects the outcome.

Comment: Or maybe, since this is a deadlock, it *sometimes* works, and it was pure chance the first time worked well. I'll fix the real problem.

Comment: See my answer below for the solution. $#!$ %$^%$#! $#$#@ AVG.

Answer (score 3):

Before taking @Hans Passant advice I carefully combed through the code, `dumpbin /dependents`ed the executables and DLLs and made sure there were no custom DllMains. There were none. DLLs were indeed loaded with LoadLibrary, but that was happening long after the loading DLLs were loaded.

So I took @Hans Passant advice. Set up the debugger properly and checked the state of the process during the deadlock. One of the threads was stuck in LdrLoadDll.

It took a little tinkering to find the name of the DLL that was passed to LdrLoadDll. It was AVGHOOK.DLL .

I disabled AVG, and lo and behold - everything is back to normal.

This is the second time AVG is messing with me. The previous time I nearly replaced a printer until I figured out all the PCL errors disappeared when I disabled AVG. I think I'm not going to use it any more.

Answer (score 1):

I have put our comment ping pong into a full text:

#1:
As you found out, that your application did not load, you needed to check if applications on your system (W10, VS2013) run at all.
**Reply:** A test console app is running fine.

#2:
If your application doesn't run, build up a similar application and step-by-step put code of your app into the new app until it fails.
If the failure is causes by a DLL (which cannot be loaded, as it was in your case), remove DLLs from your app until it works. Alternatively build a dummy console app, include DLL #1 and use some functions of that DLL. Compile, run, check. Go on until DLL #n...
**Reply:** faulty DLL was found.

#3:
Reference only this DLL in the test app to ensure it's this DLL only and not a combination of DLLs.
Is it a managed DLL or a native C++ DLL?
If the faulty DLL is from a foreign source: bad luck. Ask the developer for support.
If it's your own: Did you compile the faulty DLL on W10+VS2013, too, or did you copy it from your previous system? I suggest you compile this DLL again on the new system.
**Reply:**  it's a native C++ DLL, which is part of the solution and is compiled together with the main app.

> This DLL references other DLLs unfortunately.

#4:
Create a new console app, that references not your faulty application DLL, but the DLLs which are referenced by YOUR DLL. Omit the intermediate step to detect if the failure comes from the other DLLs.
**The general procedure is: Split up faulty code to find out out which part is causing trouble.** Romans already knew this 2000 years ago: **Divide et impera** ;-) Though they did it in a different context...

Answer (score 0):

We had the exact same problem here during several weeks ! And we finally found a solution !

In our case, it was the anti-virus Avast which was corrupting the generated .exe !

The solution was to simply disable all agents while generating the release !

If you use another anti-virus, try to disable it.